# Set image just one time on NavigationBar Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I have an app with several ViewControllers, and I have to display an image in the title of the navigation bar, I already have this code to do it.

```
public func carregarLogoNav() -> Void {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 86, height: 38))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let image = UIImage(named: "logo-simples.png")
    imageView.image = image
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
}
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to replicate this image to all other views, without having to paste this code in each one.

Another way would be to just call this function in another ViewController, but it is not working either

```
anotherViewController().carregarLogoNav()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have the same `titleView` in all of your view controllers then you can put your `carregarLogoNav` function in an extension and then call it from `viewDidLoad` of each of your view controllers:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public func setupCarregarLogoNav() {
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 86, height: 38))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let image = UIImage(named: "logo-simples.png")
        imageView.image = image
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    }
}
```

Then in each view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCarregarLogoNav()

    // any other code
}
```

This way your setup code is only in once place. It's just called from other places.

Comment: it would be perfect for me if I needed only one time, but this method worked, thanks

Comment: Another option is to create a subclass of `UIViewController` and have its `viewDidLoad` setup the `titleView`. Then all of your view controllers would need to extend that custom view controller. But if you also need table view controllers or collection view controllers, etc., you are back to where you started.